# Submitting a branched iOS project (same project name) to app store process

Tags: ios, xcode4

I have a base project, which I would like to re-brand and resell for clients. So my question is: When I branch and create a new project obviously it needs to be a separate entity from the main. Is the only thing that separates these apps during submission the Bundle ID?

Since renaming projects can sometimes be a pain, what I'm doing is:

- Creating the branch
- Opening it in XCode and changing the Target name, and this changes the bundle ID because it's set to com.whatever.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}.

So I'm wondering when submitting a new project, is the bundle ID the only thing that needs to be globally unique? or are there more attributes that I would need to change for each new branch/project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, only the bundle ID needs to be different.

A few things you should notice though:

1. You probably want the app splash screen / icon / icon label to be different between clients too
2. Under **Build Settings** your **Code Signing Entity** might need to be different too. If you have certificates+provisioning profiles which are specific to the bundle ID, you would have to create new sets of those for every client and use them when building
3. If you see that you're starting to change resources (like the icon / images for branding / string tables) between clients, using multiple projects and a shared static library may be easier for you. Take all of your shared code and convert it to a static library iOS project, and then create a separate project per client (normal iOS app project) which uses this library. This way all the metadata (like bundle ID, certificates, icons) can be different, and the code be the same.
4. If your app defines any URL schemes (for example, if you implement login with Facebook you need to do this), these schemes should be different between clients too. If they are the same, you are bound to have collisions when a user installs 2 apps on their device.

And one last tip regarding Apple policy:

If you are planning to submit all of these client apps under your developer account, this may be against Apple policy and your apps might be rejected. Apple wants you to open a dev account (and pay the $99/year) per client..

Comment: Sorry this was my question. @talkol, Yes the app has only basic resources which will be replaced for each client. Then that base project only references all the business logic. So really I'm skinning the base app for each customer. I was just making sure that the only thing that needs to be changed (since in branching, the project name is the same, just in another directory) is the bundle id. We will probably be having clients sign up for a dev account.

Comment: How exactly are you branching? and also, where exactly are you changing the target name (so the bundle id is different)?